# How to send Authorization header with http request from angular frontend to nestjs backend

Tags: angular, authentication, websocket, authorization, nestjs

I am trying to allow my angular clients to authenticate to my nestjs backend in order to only allow websockets to be opened by authorized users.

I have followed this tutorial in order to set up my Angular clients + nestjs websocket server backend: https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-simple-live-chat-server-with-nestjs-websockets/

It shows that there is an object called SocketIoConfig that takes a url and options to open a web socket connection to the nestjs backend. From my understanding in order to open a websocket the browser first sends an http request and then receives an 'upgrade to ws' response if the request was successful. I would like to attach an authorization header to this initial http request by adding headers to the options object in the SocketIoConfig object.

In client's app.module.ts I have this to open the connection:

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3333', options: { }};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ChatComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, 
SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)],
  providers: [ ChatService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What I would expect is that I could add a headers object within the options object and add the Authorization header to that, like so:

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3333', options: {
     headers: {
       Authorization: Bearer A8V342CsArf2
       }
    }
};
```

However when I open the Chrome network tab upon making the connection I do not see the Authorization header in the request headers. Why is this header not being attached to the open connection request?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the angular headers (I assume this works the same way with sockets also)

```
 headers = {
   Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`
 };

 const req = request.clone({
     url: 'http://localhost:3333',
     withCredentials: true,
     setHeaders: headers
 });
```

Comment: I tried adding the withCredentials field and setHeaders field to the options object but that didnt seem to work. Angular is making the request to the socket for me somewhere else so there is no way for me to grab the request in order to clone it and add headers

Answer (score 0):

If all of your requests are supposed to be authenticated against the same token, consider using an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses):

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer 123abc` } }));
  }

}
```

You can also get the token via a service, injected in the interceptor constructor.